# SAP B1 with C#: how to apply an input mask to an edit text

Tags: c#, sapb1

I have a "Sales Order" table. It has a column "Total (LC)". I need to check the data entry with C#. Namely, I need to enter only numbers in the field.
As far as I understand, this should work when I start entering something in this field. Do I need to use any event for the system form in Visual Studio?

I'm just starting to work in SAP B1, I'll be happy for any advice

Answer (score 2):

On The Sales Order form the Column **Total (LC)**
already has validation to ensure only numbers can be entered.

After Entering 'xxx' for example, When the user tries to exit the field SAP B1 will produce the error shown in the image below ("Invalid Monetary Value") and the user will not be able to exit the field until corrected.

[image: Entered Letters in Column]

[image: Sap Error Message]